# How to create UI like found on Bitrix24

Tags: user-interface

I am working on making a better UI for an web based app that I am working on and I found UI found on sites like Bitrix24 (CRM) is very nice. User is able to update the details and save it then and there without a page refresh. I am nit sure what technology is used by them on front end. Can someone give an insight on how such user interface can be created.

Comment: Need a lot more specifics to be able to help you. There is a possible hint in "save it then and there without a page refresh" - that is usually done using AJAX, but there are a lot of specific details involved depending on what language you are using on the server and what libraries (e.g., jQuery) on the client.

Comment: There are many frameworks with good looking controls. The fact that a user can save without refresh is trivial and is possibly due to the client issuing a direct save request to the business/db layer.

Comment: I am looking for some answer in the form of the client libraries that can be used. Server side is not an issue. It will be in the form of REST API and can be customized. I am looking for a framework which can speedily support such functionality. I am aware it can be done using Ajax as well as websockets. However, using them directly will be too much low-level as my application is extensive having about 50 UI screens.

Comment: I am looking for some answer in the form of the client libraries that can be used. Server side is not an issue. It will be in the form of REST API and can be customized. I am looking for a framework which can speedily support such functionality. I am aware it can be done using Ajax as well as websockets. However, using them directly will be too much low-level as my application is extensive having about 50 UI screens.